# Is there any way to open a PDF from blob in new window with name

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob

I am receiving a PDF as blob from API, I want to open it in new tab giving it a filename I want.

The file is being opened in new tab but the name and link looks like this

Link: "blob:http://localhost:3000/6ff6920c-2737-49cb-9359-e641e4af765d"

Name of PDF: "6ff6920c-2737-49cb-9359-e641e4af765d"
This name is different on each open

I am opening new tab with `createObjectURL`

```
const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
window.open(fileUrl);
```

So, I want to change the name of file when it is opened in new tab, instead of having auto-generated one.

Comment: Are you the end user of this system (with no access to the browser-side code)?  Or the front-end developer (with complete control of the receiving JavaScript)?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: no, I am generating also the PDF in the API

Comment: I tried to add name/fileName/ filename properties to the blob, tried to convert to FormData, but nothing helped. Also I tried to add "name" parameter to headers from API, that also did not changed nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this is currently not possible, at least not by embedding the name in a Data URL/URI.

I came across the same question today, did some research, and came to that conclusion. The Media Type part of a data URL/URI (i.e., Strings of the form `data:[<media_type>],<data>` as defined by RFC 2397) would actually allow additional parameters; e.g., `data:application/pdf;name=myPDFfile.pdf;base64,...`. Such a parameter doesn't seem to be standardized nor do the most common browsers support it.

Answer (score -1):

workaround to the problem would be

```js
var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
const newWindow:any = window.open()
newWindow.document.write(`<title>Pdf Reader</title><iframe src="${fileURL}" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>`)
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. It's not the tab title we want to control, it's the filename. Also if you want to modify the title of a tab surely you could just use newWindow.document.title = "Whatever you want"; ?

Comment: Dont remember exactly but using FileReader we can rename files, kind of recreating the file with a custom name, if you just want to rename.